# I don't know how to check for position of gameObjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm building is a Tetris word game where you have a goal word that you need to spell but you also get points for spelling other word with those letters. (for example the goal word is seaweed and you get points for spelling words like sea and weed and you win once you actually spell seaweed). Anyway, what I have right now is the starting of a tetris game without the part where it clears a line (because I want a word to clear, not a line). Each letter is its own gameObject and I don't know how to check for words. I get how to add to the score and everything, but it's the checking for words that has me stuck. This is what the game looks like sort of:

Screenshot of my screen in Unity

[image: 1]

I was thinking maybe I could check if the gameObject for each letter is in a specific sequence (positioned next to other letters that would spell out a word) but I don't know how to do that or if it would even work. If anyone could help me figure this one out I would really appreciate it. Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TetrisBlock : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float previousTime;
    public float fallTime = 0.8f;
    public static int height = 280;
    public static int width = 160;
    private static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[width, height];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-20, 0, 0);
            if (!ValidMove())
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(20, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(20, 0, 0);
            if (!ValidMove())
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-20, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if(Time.time - previousTime > (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) ? fallTime / 10 : fallTime))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -20, 0);
            if (!ValidMove())
            {
                transform.position -= new Vector3(0, -20, 0);
                AddToGrid();
                this.enabled = false;
                FindObjectOfType<SpawnerTetromino>().NewTetromino();
            }
            previousTime = Time.time;
        }

        void AddToGrid()
        {
            int roundedX = Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.x);
            int roundedY = Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.y);

            grid[roundedX, roundedY] = transform;
        }

        bool ValidMove()
        {
            {
                int roundedX = Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.x);
                int roundedY = Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.y);

                if (roundedX < 0 || roundedX >= width || roundedY < 0 || roundedY >= height)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (grid[roundedX, roundedY] != null)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides that, Tetris works with a fixed grid the tiles can be moved on -> this should make it easy for you to check positions/recognize patterns (aka words) since there is a fixed amount of grid positions you can have / your current tile can end up in

Comment: In your case if the block is only always 1x1 anyway you only have to check the up to 3 directions around it (the 4th is where it came from) for a possible match .. only after clearing tiles you would have to recheck.. sounds like a reasonable amount of work to do .. depending of course on the size of your dictionary/possible word matches

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can definitely do this.

First, you need to track the `GameObject` or `Transform` of the letters, for example: `Transform[] letters`

Then, you need to set their position, for example:

```
int width = 100;

for(int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
{
    letters[i].position = new Vector3(i*width, 0):
}
```

Another thing that you can do is, have a prefab of each letter *perhaps, even have an array of 26 where 0=A and 25=Z* then instantiate the letters based on the word and place them in order.

A final idea, is to Instantiate your letters into an object with a Horizontal Layout Group.